# Plain mathematical definition for Imagemagick's -color-matrix operation

Tags: imagemagick

How does -color-matrix work and what does ["similar to Adobe Flash"](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#color-matrix) mean? I'm looking for a plain mathematical definition.  How are the input vector(s), matrix and output vector composed?  How is the matrix applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain mathematical definition is it uses matrix multiplication.

Here is an explanation with some examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533875(v=vs.85).aspx

RGBA uses 5x5 matrix and CMYKA uses 6x6, but the idea is the same.

```
                                     [ A00 A01 A02 A03 A04 ]
                                     [ A10 A11 A12 A13 A14 ]
 [ R' G' B' A' ? ] = [ R G B A 1 ] x [ A20 A21 A22 A23 A24 ]
                                     [ A30 A31 A32 A33 A34 ]
                                     [ A40 A41 A42 A43 A44 ]
```

? is ignored.

Here is the live matrix to experiment with: http://www.adobetutorialz.com/articles/1987/1/Color-Matrix